# JQuery passing elements to load result function

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to vertically dimension an accordion panel after loading the content div with JQuery load function, but the panel is undefined inside the function. Anything wrong with it?

```
$(panel).load(url, data, function (result) {
    $(panel).style.maxHeight = $(panel).scrollHeight + "px";
});
```

Comment: Try using $(this) instead $(panel)

Comment: Still Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'maxHeight' of undefined

Comment: exactly, `$(panel).style` gives `undefined` because... well see my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several issues in your code

```
$(panel).style.maxHeight
```

is invalid since `$()` is a jQuery Object and has no `style` property. you can access the JS's Element by doing `$().get(0)` or `$()[0]`, or directly by using `this`.

`$(panel)` (in your specific case) will only be valid if prior to it you did `var panel = "#panel"`.
And you should make sure you're inside a **document ready** or your code is placed right before the closing `</body>` tag.

Here's a remake:

```js
jQuery(function($) { // DOM ready and $ alias in scope

  var url = "foobar.html";
  var data = {};
  var $panel = $("#panel"); // cache your selectors

  $panel.load(url, data, function(result) {
    $(this).css("max-height", $(this).prop("scrollHeight") );
  });

});
```

or alternatively - make use of the JS's `this` (Element reference object)

```js
jQuery(function($) { // DOM ready and $ alias in scope

  var url = "foobar.html",
      data = {},
      $panel = $("#panel");

  $panel.load(url, data, function(result) {
    this.style.maxHeight = this.scrollHeight;
  });

});
```

while inside a `function` you can reference to `$panel` using `$(this)`.
If you use **ES6 syntax** and arrow functions you can use the cached `$panel` reference:

```js
jQuery($ => { // DOM ready and $ alias in scope

  const url = "foobar.html",
    data = {},
    $panel = $("#panel");

  $panel.load(url, data, result => {
    $panel.css("max-height", $panel.prop("scrollHeight") );
  });

});
```